# How to compare two inputs with each other - Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to make a program that detects if each letter of an inputted word is in each word of the imputed sentence in order.
My program works as so.

```
Word: book
Sentence: look wow lap kill
no
yes
no
yes
```

It works fine with one word inputted. I am trying to get it to work when I input two or more words. My desired output is this.

```
Word: book dogs cowl
Sentence: look wow lap kill

book:
no
yes
no
yes

dogs:
no
yes
no
no

cowl:
no
yes
no
yes
```

My code that only works with one word inputted. I understand that if i change the my variable named cc it will change the word that is being compared to the sentence. For example if cc was changed to 1 the word being compared would become dogs instead of book. This allows me to compare only one word at a time, but I want to compare all of the imputed words at the same time.  I'm not sure how to implement it into a loop.

```
f = input("Word: ")
gg = f.split(" ")
m = input("Sentence: ")
n = m.split(" ")
y = []
c = 0
cc = 0 #CHANGE THIS AND IT CHANGES THE WORD THAT IS BEING COMPARED TO THE SENTENCE
g = (gg[cc])
l = list(g[c])
while c < len(g):
  if g[c] in n[c]:
    print("yes")
    if g not in y:
      y.append(g)
  else:
    y[:] = [item for item in y if item != g]
    print("no")
  c = c+1
```

Comment: Sidenote : You should really take the time to give good names to your variables. it will help you in the long run.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused by the question. If you want to apply the loop to multiple inputs, I suggest putting the loop inside a function and calling it with arguments.

Comment: Will - just an aside - you may wish to consider reading - [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - it appears you've received a lot of answers previously that look like they've probably been of use to you. When people provide such answers, it's generally considered polite you accept them if they have helped you. Otherwise, for fairly trivial questions like this, if people look at your profile, they may not consider it worth answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... This should work for you

```
word = input("Words: ")
words = word.split(" ")
sentence = input("Sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.split(" ")
for a_word in words:
    j=0
    for letter in a_word:
        if letter in sentence[j]:
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")
        j+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this,

```
f = input("Word: ")
gg = f.split(" ")
m = input("Sentence: ")
n = m.split(" ")
for i in gg:
    print('%s:'%i)
    for ind,j  in enumerate(i):
        if j in n[ind]:
            print('%s- Yes'%j)
        else:
            print('%s- No'%j)
```

here is the output,

```
mohideen@botvfx-dev:~$ python Desktop/run.py 
Word: book dogs cowl
Sentence: look wow lap kill
book:
b - No
o - Yes
o - No
k - Yes
dogs:
d - No
o - Yes
g - No
s - No
cowl:
c - No
o - Yes
w - No
l - Yes
mohideen@botvfx-dev:~$
```